# UIView rotated by 45° disappears?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

maybe I don't get. When I do

```
self.tweetPeak.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(45));
```

where RADIAN is

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)
```

on a simple UIView Object it will disappear.

I guess it's just to thin to see. My impression is that the view is getting smaller in a range between 20 to 45 degrees.

What is it? I tried to set the view opaque. No effect.

chris

Comment: Is it possible that it's being rotated out of the screen?

Comment: Not related but `RADIONS` is a horrible name for that define. It gives no indication of what it is doing or how to use it.

Comment: @Paul.s that's a matter of style, IMO, that is a fine name for a macro, but I have seen it labeled `TO_RADIANS`, `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS` and such forth. It really just depends on what you need.

Comment: Well `RADIANS` is too ambiguous am I supposed to give it radions or normalised values or degrees. Does it return radians convert from radians to degrees, store it some where.... who knows. `DEGREES_TO_RADIANS` seems the most descriptive

Comment: I have tried also with your #define and a normal UIView and all works ok, maybe there is another problem.

Comment: can you post the code that you use for this?

Comment: Okay, I got it. The parent view was resized to fit in a formSheet and the autoresizemask did the rest. Thanks for helping.

#radians I think I'll use M_PI_4 constant instead of bugging around with degrees.  

chris

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to stop adjusting the frame after the rotation, it causes undesired stretching to the transform matrix, I'm unsure to the formal reason why, but it has something to do with Apple using their own matrix system rather than traditional matrices to represent 2D/3D translations/rotations/scale. I was having the same problem the other day, to fix it, instead of rotating that view, I just made it a container with the actual view I wanted rotated inside, and rotated that.

Comment: CGAffineTransform and CATransform3D are absolutely standard, traditional matrices. Apple is not doing anything weird there.  Your problem is that `-[CALayer frame]` is a _derived_ value -- it's based on the `position`, `bounds`, `anchorPoint`, and `transform` properties. If you change the transform, the frame will change. If you then try to change the frame, the layer will try to adjust the position and bounds.size to make it work. Solution: don't set the frame.

Comment: If a CATransform3D is a traditional matrix how come I cannot setup, say a traditional orthogonal matrix and still see my layer? Or a perspective one at that? I mean I'm not doubting you, but they don't quite use it traditionally, why does .m34 control something that is akin to FOV? None of this is quite standard if you ask me. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I've been searching for quite a bit trying to figure this out.  Your two comments really helped me understand my problem.  For anyone else running into this... I had some initialization where I wanted some labels rotated.  I had this in viewDidLoad... I had to move it to viewDidAppear to get things working correctly (as the frame is still being set until after viewWillAppear).

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to set the imageView content mode to `.center`

`imageView.contentMode = .center`