# How to rotate UIView by 45 degrees?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to rotate my `UIButton` by `M_PI/4` with animation. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.closeButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4);
    }];
}
```

But this make my button's frame corrupted. Frame before animation was `(260 0; 44 44)` and after animation it becomes `(250.887 -9.1127; 62.2254 62.2254)`.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547122/uiview-rotated-by-45-disappears) post and few others, but I don't understand, how to achieve UIButton animated rotation by `M_PI/2`.

Comment: Is the problem, not being able to rotate the button or that the button's frame is corrupted?

Comment: @Aaron, the problem is I want to rotate button around its center, but i get unvisible button with corrupted frame instead

Comment: By "frame", do you mean the values of the `frame` property or do you mean the border of the button?

Answer (score 4):

Xcode - 10
Swift - 4x

```
self.yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/4)
```

this can help you rotate your uiview to 45 degree

Answer (score 3):

The [`frame` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) is invalid once you've applied a transformation. According to the documentation:

> **Warning:** If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So as long as the result *looks* alright this is expected behavior.

If you want to move the button, you need to save the transformation, reset it to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`, set the new frame, then re-apply the old transformation. Alternatively, you *may* access and modify the `center` property of the frame even when a transformation is applied.

Comment: I tried to save center before transformation and set old center, unsuccessfully

Comment: I'm afraid we're still guessing what you really mean. You need to be more specific: 1) Is the button rotated when you don't animate it and when you do not change the center/frame? 2) Can you see the button but it looks distorted? 3) Can you see the button but it's not where you want it to be?

Answer (score 3):

The `frame` of a UIView is the smallest rectangle that fully encloses the view.  When you rotate by PI/2 the frame will expand by sqrt(2), and the origin will be adjusted to keep the center at the same point, which is exactly what happened.

If you want the button to rotate and keep its same frame, you need to squash the button as it rotates, like this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGFloat w = self.closeButton.bounds.size.width  / sqrtf( 2.0f );
    CGFloat h = self.closeButton.bounds.size.height / sqrtf( 2.0f );
    NSLog( @"%@ w=%f", NSStringFromCGRect( self.closeButton.bounds ), w );

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.closeButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4);
        self.closeButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, w, h );
    }];

    NSLog( @"%@", NSStringFromCGRect( self.closeButton.frame ) );
}
```

Comment: Setting the bounds doesn't influence the frame. This way you can have a view have a different "inner" coordinate system than on the outside. When you rotate the view, the "inner" system doesn't know it's rotated and thus doesn't need to have its size modified.

Comment: Sigh, try the code, print out the frame before and after.  Be enlightened.

Comment: You're right, it _does_ affect the frame (found out the sizes are coupled). But it doesn't affect the displayed button in the slightest once the transform is applied, though (tried with text and image button and measured the result). It does when the transform is identity. Can easily be tested by doubling `w` and `h`, then look at the result with or without setting the transform.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're fighting auto-layout. Try this in a project that has auto-layout disabled.

Comment: Yes, switching off auto-layout did make a change: now if I mess with the bounds the view isn't rotating around its center any more, the rotation point is slightly offset. I still stand by my initial point: _Messing with the bounds is unnecessary here._ If all you want is rotate it by 45 degrees around its center, set the transform and be done. But unless the OP finally explains his issues we won't be able to help him anyway.